# Where should I find how the indexOf function is written for JavaScript core looks like?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, substring, indexof

I want to see it because there is an algorithm interview question asked similar thing but no one was able to resolve it without some sort of internal function like `indexOf()` which would have been perfectly fine except that the requirement was NOT to use an internal function to resolve this.
Since I think the best implementation is already there, why don't I just learn from the best? Which I suppose is how they wrote `.indexOf()` for String already in JavaScript.

My solution was humiliating to even show it... so I decide not to, in other words, there are way too much conditional toggling than I would want to put in there.

Thanks

Question is following

> Avoid using built-in functions to solve this challenge. Implement them
>   yourself, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real
>   interview.
>
> Implement a function that takes two strings, s and x, as arguments and
>   finds the first occurrence of the string x in s. The function should
>   return an integer indicating the index in s of the first occurrence of
>   x. If there are no occurrences of x in s, return -1.
>
> Example
>
> For s = "CodefightsIsAwesome" and x = "IA", the output should be
>   strstr(s, x) = -1; For s = "CodefightsIsAwesome" and x = "IsA", the
>   output should be strstr(s, x) = 10. Input/Output
>
> [time limit] 4000ms (js) [input] string s
>
> A string containing only uppercase or lowercase English letters.
>
> Guaranteed constraints: 1 ≤ s.length ≤ 106.
>
> [input] string x
>
> String, containing only uppercase or lowercase English letters.
>
> Guaranteed constraints: 1 ≤ x.length ≤ 106.
>
> [output] integer
>
> An integer indicating the index of the first occurrence of the string
>   x in s, or -1 if s does not contain x

Bitw its from codefight
https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/C8Jdyk3ybixqQdAvM

For anyone interested to test their code in full with all test cases, its here (see where my cursor is pointing to in the image vvv?)

https://codefights.com/interview-practice/topics/strings
[image]

Comment: `but no one was able to resolve it` how do you know? I mean, this is simple to write

Comment: by looked at the top solutions got voted up in JS in codefights as well as whats already on stackoverflow? @Jaromanda X

Comment: V8 (the JavaScript engine in Chrome) and SpiderMonkey (the JavaScript engine in Firefox) are both open source...

Comment: The problem is `indexOf` is most likely written in C++ as it's a core function of the String object.  And if your challenge is to write it in Javascript, it's not really going to help you is it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: `[time limit] 4000ms` - when was this written? 2 days after Brendan wrote javascript?

Answer (score 6):

> no one was able to resolve it

I'm a little shocked that was the case, as it's just 2 simple nested for loops.  Eg, it took me less than a few minutes to knock this up.

```js
function strstr(a,b) {
  for (var o = 0; a[o]; o ++)
  {
    var found = true;
    for (var i = 0; b[i]; i ++) {
      if (a[o + i] !== b[i]) { found=false; break; }
    } 
    if (found) return o;
  }
  return -1;
}

var s = "CodefightsIsAwesome";
var x = "IA";

console.log(strstr(s, x));

s = "CodefightsIsAwesome";
x = "IsA";

console.log(strstr(s, x));
```

Comment: surely you don't need to use `.length` property :p

Comment: @JaromandaX  That's true,.  but might make things more obvious for the OP.  I've updated to remove length.

Comment: interesting solution! @Keith but it did not pass all the hidden test for codeflight.... so yea... not exactly a perfect solution

Comment: Sample tests: 14/14
Hidden tests: 7/13
Score: 68/300

Comment: @Ezeewei  Your  link takes me to a page I need to login,. I assume the scoring is based on all the other criteria. eg. `A string containing only uppercase or lowercase`.  But then it doesn't say what should happen if these are not met, is it meant to return -1, or raise an exception.??  But given the 2 examples it does provide, it passes 100%..

Comment: @Keith hey its in no way I put down your answer! I rather appreciate it! Just wonder if the answer is that simple when it pass all tests! I updated the question and list the actual place where you can test your code!

Comment: @Ezeewei Don't worry, never took it that way.  But just not sure what there after.  Just done a run, it's failing because of time limits, I never even thought of making this optimised.  That `106` your have is 10 to the power 6,.so I assume it's failing with large inputs.  With some extra optimisations I think it should work.  I can think of one already, aka. The outer loops can use length - inner length.

Comment: Ok, solved it.  The trick is to create a simple rolling hash..  So first get the hash for search string, then get the hash of the first set of chars same length.  If the hash is the same, do a full check again.  if not subtract the hash of the first char, and add the hash of the new char,. compare hash again..  Doing this it passed..  The hash I simply added & subtracted the values from charCodeAt..

Comment: @Keith awesome! would you update this answer to the one pass the test in full? I would LOVE to mark this as the best answer!!! Thanks man!!!

Comment: Isn't the whole point of that site to test yourself?.  If I simply post the answer I did, it's not really helping you.  I'd much rather explain in a little bit more detail what I did, and you implement it. Like I said the trick is to create a rolling hash, this means it only requires one single pass of both strings.  That's what speeds it up.  Would you like me to add more details?. ps.. The rolling hash doesn't even have to be complicated, just a simple summation..

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript runs on ECMAScript Engines. ECMAScript is nothing but the specification of JavaScript. Different browser provides different implementation for that, like Chrome has V8 engine implementation for ECMAScript, similarly Carakan for Opera.
>   [Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-code-behind-JavaScript-functions-and-methods-Where-can-I-find-the-source-code-for-JavaScript-or-other-language-functions)

So with that in mind... Here you might get some more information on how things work:

[ECMA Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14)

General MDN entry: [Click](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: The spec isn't going to give the OP *"...the best implementation..."* The spec lays out the logic for what should happen, not necessarily the best *implementation* of that logic. (In fact, frequently *not* the best implementation of it.)

Comment: Well, he wanted to know where to find the indexOf implementation. And in fact, that's where he finds it. This is exactly how it works. Lurking deeper in V8 might eventually take him to the C++ implementation.

Comment: @Akaino so basically if I want to know how indexOf() is implemented, I kinda has to know C? and both V8 and .... other engine?